# Counting the number of nonnegative integer solutions

Tags: combinatorics

The constraints are

$x_1+x_2+x_3=5,\qquad (1)$ 
$y_1+y_2+y_3=7,\qquad \; (2)$ 
$x_1 \geq 3,\qquad \qquad \qquad \;\; (3)$ 
$0 \leq y_2 \leq 2,\qquad \qquad \;\;\;(4)$ 
$x_2+y_2 \geq 1,\qquad \qquad \;\, (5)$ 
$x_3+y_3 \geq 1.\qquad \qquad \;\; (6)$

How to handle the dependency between $x$'s and $y$'s in the last two constraints?

Comment: Ignore the constraints first, and then subtract the number of solutions where the constraints are violated (since a violation of the constraints means $x_2 = y_2 = 0$ or $x_3 = y_3 = 0$, the violating solutions are easily counted).

Comment: That's nifty, thanks! Can you put it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Doing a small transformation (letting $a_1=x_1+3$ and $a_2=x_2,a_3=x_3,b_1=y_1,b_2=y_2,b_3=y_3$) what we want is the number of nonnegative solutions to $a_1+a_2+a_3=2$ and $b_1+b_2+b_3=7$ satisfying the last three conditions. (so this transformation helps us get rid of the first constraint)

We separate depending on the values of $a_1,a_2,a_3$.

Case $1: (a_1,a_2,a_3)=(2,0,0)$. We then need $b_2=1$ or $2$ and $b_3>0$. When $b_2=1$ we have $6$ options, when $b_2=2$ we have $5$ options. So $11$ total.

Cases $2$ and $3: (a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,0)$ or $(0,2,0)$. Then $b_2=0,1$ or $2$ and $b_3>0$. When $b_2=0$ there are $7$ options, when $b_2=1$ we have $6$ options and when $b_2=2$ we have $5$ options. So $16$ total

Cases $4$ and $5: (a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,0,1)$ or $(0,0,2)$ Then we need $b_2=1$ or $2$. When $b_2=1$ we have $7$ options and when $b_2=2$ we have $6$ options, so $13$ options in total.

Case $6: (a_1,a_2,a_3)=(0,1,1)$. We need $a_2=0,1,2$. When $b_2=0$ there are $8$ options when $b_2=1$ we have $7$ and when $b_2=2$ we have $6$, so $21$ in total.

So there are $11+16+16+13+13+21=90$

Comment: Thank you but I have a different answer using @Daniel Fischer's trick.

i. No. of solutions satisfying (1)-(4): $6\times(36-15)=126.$<br/>
ii. No. of solutions satisfying (1)-(4) and $x_2=y_2=0$: $3\times8=24.$
iii. No. of solutions satisfying (1)-(4) and $x_3=y_3=0$: $3\times(8-5)=9.$
iv. No. of solutions satisfying (1)-(4) and $x_2=y_2=x_3=y_3=0$: $1.$

Hence we have $126-24-9+1=94$ solutions.

Comment: I don't think you are taking into account restriction $4$ in the following calculation: number of solutions satisfying $1-4$ and $x_2=y_2=x_3=y_3=0$. The answer should be $0$ because $x_1$ would be $7$, violating restriction $4$. I think you also forgot about condition $4$ when counting other cases. please respond.

Comment: For the constraints (1)-(4) and $x_2=y_2=x_3=y_3=0$, $(x_1,y_1)=(5,7)$ and that's the only solution I can think of.

Comment: Oh ok, i for some reason had it down like $y_1\leq 2$, I'll redo everything.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's safe to assume $x$'s and $y$'s are independent sans $(5) - (6)$ but to handle $(4)$, I subtract the number of solutions satisfying (2)& $y_2 \geq 3$ from the number of solutions satisfying only $(2)$.

Comment: I got $90$ solutions, I did it again.

Comment: Don't we have $4\cdot8$ solutions satisfying $(1)-(4)$ and $x_2=y_2=0$?

Comment: I think we only have $3\cdot 8$.

Comment: aren't there $4*8-1$? There are $4$ ways to select $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and 4then $8$ ways to select $y_1,y_2,y_3$? The four ways are $(3,0,4),(4,0,3),(5,0,2),(6,0,1),(7,0,0)$

Comment: Because $x_1+x_3=5$ so you can only have $(x_1,x_3)=(3,2), (4,1)$ or $(5,0)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad.

Comment: Hey just want to say thank you for working through this problem with me. It's getting late over here so I'm off to sleep now but I'll continue with you when I wake up!